# iTextSharp letter show in pdf on click

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext, pdf-generation

Filling existing pdf file fields with itextsharp.

Everything is ok except the part for some reason letter "ć" is not visible on textbox.

It show like this on preview and print

[image]

But when i click on field i see the hidden letter "ć"

[image]

What i have tried.

Font size making smaller
Font style making different

This is the complete code for editing this field

```
If IIf(IsDBNull(_row("II")), 0, _row("II")) = 0 Then
    pdfFormFields.SetField("II", "Prvo izvješće")
ElseIf IIf(IsDBNull(_row("II")), 0, _row("II")) = 1
    pdfFormFields.SetField("II", "Ispravak")
Else
    pdfFormFields.SetField("II", "Dopuna")
End If
```

What am i making wrong here :(.

PDF : [Entire PDF document](https://1drv.ms/b/s!ArPw7iH1ZL8HgpVkJ0rlt6dUMfAqxQ?e=xf03Mj)

Edit: After adding substitution font the result is bellow

[image]

Comment: Cam you share the pdf in question?

Comment: @mkl i just attached the pdf

Comment: The field **II** has the default appearance `/Calibri 8 Tf 0 g`. The font **Calibri** in your PDF is defined with encoding **WinAnsiEncoding**. The letter 'ć' is not present in this encoding. Thus, the PDF producer knowingly or unknowingly attempted to keep you from entering that letter. It should be possible, nonetheless, to fill that in with iTextSharp if you provide a replacement font for letters not present in the preset font. I'll look into that later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field **II** has the default appearance `/Calibri 8 Tf 0 g`. The font **Calibri** in your PDF is defined with encoding **WinAnsiEncoding**. The letter 'ć' is not present in this encoding. Thus, the PDF producer knowingly or unknowingly attempted to keep you from entering that letter. If you provide a substitution font, though, that knows that character, you can fill in that field as desired.

#### Reproducing the issue

```
using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(@"JOPPD.pdf"))
using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, File.Create(@"JOPPD-FilledLikeProgramerAnel.pdf")))
{
    stamper.AcroFields.SetField("II", "Prvo izvješće");
}
```

results in

[image: JOPPD-FilledLikeProgramerAnel_Seite_1.png]

#### Fixing it with a substitution font

```
using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(@"JOPPD.pdf"))
using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, File.Create(@"JOPPD-FilledLikeProgramerAnelImproved.pdf")))
{
    BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(@"c:\Windows\Fonts\arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true);
    stamper.AcroFields.AddSubstitutionFont(baseFont);
    stamper.AcroFields.SetField("II", "Prvo izvješće");
}
```

results in

[image: JOPPD-FilledLikeProgramerAnelImproved_Seite_1.png]

Comment: Thanks for your effort but now i missing the other letter. Take a look on edited question

Comment: @ProgramerAnel which viewer do you use? I made the screen shots in my answer using Adobe Reader, and it shows all characters with the substitution font. Which itextsharp version do you use? I use the newest 5.5.x version.

Comment: You mention *preview* in your question. Previewers are notorious for showing pdfs incorrectly.

Comment: @mki iTextSharp version is 5.5.10 and you are correct. Opening pdf file in chrome gave me the desired output. But opening same pdf in Acrobat Reader 2019.12 wasn't good. Don't know what may be the issue with reader but anyway thanks for your help

Comment: *"But opening same pdf in Acrobat Reader 2019.12 wasn't good."* -  That's interesting, I'm using 2019.012.20040 and it looks good. I also used my good old Acrobat Pro 9.5, and there it also looks good. Please try the second piece of code in my answer as is. If the result thereof is better than for your result PDF, there might be something else in your code to improve.